# Locating path to style sheet for webfontloader - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, font-face, loader

I am building my first website using ReactJS and need to include a font using @font-face. After some research I found out that I need to use web font loader, and have found and installed this component:

https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

I have been following the instructions ok, but have run into a snag:
I am unsure how to point the component to where my index.scss file is located.

For some more context, the documentation I am following tells me to use the following:

```
WebFontConfig = {
  custom: {
    families: ['My Font', 'My Other Font:n4,i4,n7'],
    urls: ['/fonts.css']
  }
};
```

"fonts.css" in this case is the css document where the @font-face is declared. In my case, it will be in my index.scss file. 
(note that I am calling this in the constructor of my App.js, which I don't know if that is correct or perhaps part of my problem?)

I am calling the above code from my App.js file. Here is a screens hot of where these files are located in relation to each other:

[image]

I have tried several permutations to get this working, but so far no luck. I keep getting the following error:

> webfontloader.js:51 GET
>   file:///D:/Projects/Q4/Website%20redesign/q4portal-master/q4portal/webpack/dist-dev/styles/index.css
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

This leads me to understand that the folder structure changes when my application is compiled with Webpack. This makes sense, but how would I then point to this index.scss file?

Below is a simplified version of the App.js file for further information:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    WebFont.load({
      custom: {
        families: ['My Font'],
        urls: ['./styles/index.css']
      }
    });
  }

  render = _ => {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately my React knowledge is sparse, so I am not even sure what to Google to try an resolve this issue. Any advice would thus be very much appreciated.